# Determine 2 diagrams relative position using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, math, .net-3.5, diagram

I have two arrays of points: `double[] minus` and `double[] plus`, e.g.:

```
double[] minus = new[]
{
    24.043414306636713,
    26.521399902043807,
    23.049167719142361,
    24.473177606966754,
    18.238281854192408,
};

double[] plus = new[]
{
    8.31219054269323,
    9.5909890877229582,
    11.066525870449567,
    22.769068312057193,
    24.733540360065991,
};
```

I need to plot 2 diagrams basing on this number and determine their positions relatively to each other: are there an intersection and which of them is under another?

How can I do that? TIA

(please feel free to retag the question or change the topic, I'm not sure in proper math terminology used)

**Edit:** Here's an Excel diagram:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEhcs.png]

It's easy to determine which is above and which is under.

How to determine that red (plus) has an **intersection** with blue (minus)? Using maybe LINQ?

Comment: Could you give a numeric/visual example of what you need ?

Comment: Seems like a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/. It's not about programming, but about geometry & basic collision detection.

Comment: @MainMa: Basic collision detection is on-topic here.

Comment: @MainMa: Especially if I want to use LINQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can found all collisions:

```
double[] minus = new double[]
{
    3, 24, 26, 23, 25, 18, 5,  5,  1, 10,
};
double[] plus = new ![alt text][1]double[]
{
    3,  8,  9, 11, 22, 25, 5,  5,  3, 7
};

var collisionsBetweenIndices =
Enumerable.Range(1, minus.Length - 1)
          .Where(i => ((minus[i - 1] - plus[i - 1] < 0) && (minus[i] - plus[i] > 0)) ||
                      ((minus[i - 1] - plus[i - 1] > 0) && (minus[i] - plus[i] < 0)) ||
                      ((minus[i - 1] - plus[i - 1] == 0) && (minus[i] - plus[i] == 0)))
          .ToArray();

var collisionsOnIndices =
Enumerable.Range(0, minus.Length)
          .Where(i => minus[i] == plus[i])
          .ToArray();

foreach (var idx in collisionsBetweenIndices)
    Console.WriteLine("Collision between {0} and {1}", idx - 1, idx);

foreach (var idx in collisionsOnIndices)
    Console.WriteLine("Collision on {0}", idx);

// RESULTS:
// Collision between 4 and 5
// Collision between 6 and 7
// Collision between 8 and 9
// Collision on 0
// Collision on 6
// Collision on 7
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I did two different methods to distinguish the type of collisions (i.e. between indices or on indices), but if your purpouse is just to detect if there's a collision or not, just do the following:

```
var collisionDetected =
Enumerable.Range(0, minus.Length).Any(i =>
{
    if (minus[i] == plus[i])
        return true;
    if (i > 0 &&
        (((minus[i - 1] - plus[i - 1] < 0) && (minus[i] - plus[i] > 0)) ||
        ((minus[i - 1] - plus[i - 1] > 0) && (minus[i] - plus[i] < 0)) ||
        ((minus[i - 1] - plus[i - 1] == 0) && (minus[i] - plus[i] == 0))))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

This code returns as soon as a collision is found, so it's generally faster the the above methods.

Comment: Great! How do you think can I determine intersection existence using `bool b = Range(..).Count(..) > 0;` using your condition?

Answer (score 4):

To determine which is higher, just compare minus[i] to plus[i] - whichever has the greater value is the "higher" one at i.

To determine intersections, just keep track of which one is higher.  When that changes, there was an intersection.

**Edit**

If you can't track history, then:

```
if ((minus[i-1] > plus[i-1]) != (minus[i] > plus[i])) then
  // there was an intersection
else
  // there was not an intersection
```

Comment: I can't track the history of changes. Each tick I query data to gather this two arrays and need to determine intersection existence

Comment: @Abatishcrev: You don't need the entire history, just keep track of which one was higher previously.  If you are asking if there's a way to tell if the lines intersected between x=4 and x=5 without remembering anything about what the values were at x=4, then the answer is obviously no.

Comment: @BlueRaja: My class is stateless and it queries some data storage. It can query the data for previous n steps. This way I populate the arrays. And want to determine intersection in data I gathered.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to break each series up into line-segments, and then compare corresponding (by index) segments from the two series.

Since you *specifically* mention LINQ, here's one way to achieve that. It's not very pretty:

```
var minusPairs = minus.Zip(minus.Skip(1), (prev, next) => new { prev, next });
var plusPairs = plus.Zip(plus.Skip(1), (prev, next) => new { prev, next });

var positions = minusPairs.Zip
               (plusPairs, (mPair, pPair) =>
                mPair.prev > pPair.prev 
                     && mPair.next > pPair.next ? "MinusAbove" :
                mPair.prev < pPair.prev
                     && mPair.next < pPair.next ? "PlusAbove" :
               "Intersection");
```

Output:

```
MinusAbove
MinusAbove
MinusAbove
Intersection
```

(Note that you don't get a `PlusAbove` for the last point because the only segment it is part of represents an `Intersection`. You may need to change this behaviour if desirable.)

To be honest, I would shy away from any 'cute' solution if you need to do anything even *slightly* more complicated than this (e.g. finding the intersection points). Good OO design is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do:

```
for i=1...n
    if minus[i] > plus[i]
         return "Crossed over at index i"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public string DetermineCollisionInfo(double current, double next)
{
  string currentInfo =
    current == 0.0 ? "Plus and Minus have same value" :
    current < 0.0 && next > 0.0 ? "Intersection occurs" :
    current > 0.0 && next < 0.0 ? "Intersection occurs" :
    "No Intersection";

  string nextInfo =
    next > 0.0 ? "Plus will be on top" :
    next < 0.0 ? "Minus will be on top" :
    "Plus and Minus will have same value";

  return currentInfo + ".  " + nextInfo;
}
```

Then, later:

```
IEnumerable<double> differences = Enumerable
    .Range(0, minus.Length)
    .Select(i => plus[i] - minus[i]);

double current = differences.First();
IEnumerable<string> analysis = differences
  .Skip(1)
  .Select(next =>
  {
    string result = DetermineCollisionInfo(current, next);
    current = next;
    return result;
  });

foreach(string info in analysis)
{
  Console.WriteLine(analysis);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `minus` and `plus` are list:

```
var plus1 = plus.Skip(1);
var retVal = minus
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((p,i) => new { index = i, value = (minus[i] > plus[i]) != (p > plus1[i])})
    .Where( p => !p.value);
```